# Expect Script for Command Line

Tags: bash, scripting, expect

I am writing a script that will allow a Linux admin to quickly change passwords of its users.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# Check password for strength 
# ----------------------------------------------
read -p "What's your username?" current_user
read -p "What's the root password?" pass
read -p "How many users?" num
COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt $num ]; do
         let index=COUNTER+1
             read -p "Enter username$index : " user_$index
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done
read -p "Enter password : " password
echo 
echo "Tesing password strength..."
echo
result="$(cracklib-check <<<"$password")"
okay="$(awk -F': ' '{ print $2}' <<<"$result")"
if [[ "$okay" == "OK" ]]
then
    echo "PASSWORD ACCEPTED"
    echo "Modifying User Passwords..."
    COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt $num ]; do
             let index=COUNTER+1
             tmp=user_$index
             echo "Changing Password for " ${!tmp}
             echo ${!tmp}
             sudo passwd ${!tmp}
             expect -exact "[sudo] password for $current_user: "
             send "$pass\r"
             expect -exact "New password: "
             send "$password\r"
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done

    #echo "$user:$password" | usr/sbin/chpasswd
else
    echo "Your password was rejected - $result"
        echo "Try again."
fi
```

However, the expect portion, which would automate the inputting of passwords, is not highlighted in my editor and does not work. I keep getting prompts to manually enter text. This is especially surprising since the script is sourcing expect, not bash. I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours. Can anyone please lend me a hand?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. It's declared like an `expect` script, but the body clearly isn't one. I suspect you've gone down the wrong path several steps ago, but I can't really tell from what you've presented where that was.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing expect and bash code. Your script is principally a bash script, so
replace the top line by `#!/bin/bash`. Then replace the lines:

```
sudo passwd ${!tmp}
expect -exact "[sudo] password for $current_user: "
send "$pass\r"
expect -exact "New password: "
send "$password\r"
```

by a call to a function `mychangepw` with the args that expect
needs, i.e. the current user, sudo password, user to change, and their password:

```
mychangepw $current_user "$pass" ${!tmp} "$password"
```

Add the function to the start of the script and use it to
pass the args to expect, with the expect script on stdin upto the line "!":

```
mychangepw(){
    expect -d - "$@" <<\!
    set current_user [lindex $argv 0]
    set sudopass [lindex $argv 1]
    set user [lindex $argv 2]
    set password [lindex $argv 3]
    spawn sudo passwd $user
    expect -exact "\[sudo\] password for $current_user: "
    send "$sudopass\r"
    expect -exact "New password: "
    send "$password\r"
!
}
```

Be careful with the line starting "!". It must be the first and only char of the line, with no indent nor
additional whitespace nor comments etc.